# 1. Am I freeing memory correctly? 2. What's happening in the second for loop to cause an abundance of chars to be printed after the first iteration?

Tags: c

Am I freeing memory correctly in this program with just free(lineArr) at the end of main()?

I still can't figure out what's causing the issue with all the chars in my output (image attached). I know it's probably something basic with how I have the for loops set up.. things print correctly the first run after compiling, but not the second run. Why would this be?

Thanks

```
// When the sum of proper divisors for a number is the same as the number
// itself, the "status" of that sum may be considered "perfect"; when less,
// "deficient", and when greater than, "abundant".
//
// This program takes two extra command-line arguments after the executable
// name: an integer and a character. The integer will be the number of
// numbers past 2 to print statuses and histogram bars for; the character
// will be used to construct a histogram bar with height = to the sum of
// divisors for a particular number. Example arguments: ./a.out 6 '*'
// Example output:
// 2 is Deficient     *
// 3 is Deficient     *
// 4 is Deficient     ***
// 5 is Deficient     *
// 6 is Perfect       ******
    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
    
int sumOfDivisiors(int aNum);  //prototype for sumOfDivisiors function
    
typedef struct{  //define a structure called "line" with three members
    int  lineNum;
    int  sum;
    char status[10];
}line;
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  //main will accept command line arguments
    
    int howMany;
    char usrChar;
    line whichLine;
    
    if(argc < 3){
        printf("Error: must enter 3 command line arguments.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d", &howMany);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &usrChar);
    
    line** lineArr = malloc(howMany * sizeof(line*));  //allocate mem for array of struct ptrs
    if (lineArr == NULL){
        printf("Error: trouble allocating memory. Exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    for (int n = 2; n <= howMany; n++){  //loop to call func + initialize lineNum, sum, status for current line
        int sumResult = sumOfDivisiors(n);
        lineArr[n] = malloc(sizeof(line));  //allocate mem for pointer to current line struct
        if (lineArr[n] == NULL){
            printf("Error: trouble allocating memory. Exiting.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        line* temp = lineArr[n];
        temp->lineNum = n;
        temp->sum = sumResult;
    
        if (temp->sum == n){
            strcpy(temp->status, "Perfect");
        } else if (temp->sum < n){
            strcpy(temp->status, "Deficient");
        } else {
            strcpy(temp->status, "Abundant");
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= howMany; i++){  //loop to print formatted results
        printf("%3d %-10s ", i, lineArr[i]->status);
        for (int j = 0; j < lineArr[i]->sum; j++){
            printf("%c", usrChar);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    free(lineArr);  //free dynamically allocated memory
    return 0;
}
    
//Definition for sumOfDivisiors function. This function accepts an int number
//as an argument. It takes that number, finds all proper divisors (divisors
//less than the number itself), then returns the integer result of adding
//up all these divisors.
int sumOfDivisiors(int aNum){
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(aNum); i++){
        if (aNum % i == 0){
            if (i == (aNum/i)){
                result += i;
            } else {
                result += (i + aNum/i);
            }
        }
    }
    return(result + 1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of struct pointers instead of just an array of struct?

Comment: Answer to the first question, no you're not freeing the memory correctly. You're first allocating space for a bunch of pointers and only then allocating space for your structs. In the end, you only end up freeing the first allocation. Consider just allocating the data straight up, i.e. `line *lineArr = malloc(howMany * sizeof(line));`

Comment: Answer to second question: `result += (i + aNum/i);`

Comment: The second loop is working correctly, your `sumOfDivisors()` function is wrong.

Comment: Why do you even need the struct and array? You can just print the output in the first loop.

Comment: That does not hold true when you are `realloc()` ing memory previously allocated.

Comment: Ok I see that's it's printing out the extra chars whenever I input an even number, but seems to work correctly with odd #s